# A server installation Query

Tags: java

A user has asked us to setup a server with :

Designing Tool                     : MS-FrontPage.
Front End                : JSP, Servlets.(jdk-6)[Java].

Can anyone explain what Front End line specifies in layman terms ? How do I go about installing them ? I know about Apache PHP etc from that perspective ...

Is JSP like your APACHE ? and Servlet ( a type of programming )is a feature that comes along with Java Development KIT ? ANyone explain this in simple terms

Answer (score 1):

You typically run JSP sites on [Tomcat Server](http://tomcat.apache.org/), in the same way you run PHP sites on Apache.

You need to install a Java runtime environment for Tomcat to compile the pages, there are actually a few different ones you can use. In this case your user is asking for the official Sun JDK release, which includes both the Java runtime environment and the tools necessary for debugging and compiling code.

Comment: Thanks but what is servlet then ? 
How does that come into picture ?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that too much, it's just a name given to server side scripts that receive input through a web app, process it and generate a response. In that sense you could call PHP pages "servlets". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet